# CORS error using raspberry pi 4 "ubuntu server" with ip

Tags: java, php, html, c++

Last days I've been trying deepspeech server for text to speech using a node server. At first time, in a local host at windown worked, but after that I went into a ubuntu server connected to the router and things went harder. 
The code in **server.js** is:

```
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const DeepSpeech = require('deepspeech');
const VAD = require('node-vad');

let DEEPSPEECH_MODEL = __dirname + '/deepspeech-0.6.0-models'; // path to deepspeech english model directory

let SILENCE_THRESHOLD = 200; // how many milliseconds of inactivity before processing the audio

const SERVER_PORT = 4000; // websocket server port

// const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.NORMAL;
// const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.LOW_BITRATE;
// const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.AGGRESSIVE;
const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.VERY_AGGRESSIVE;
const vad = new VAD(VAD_MODE);

function createModel(modelDir, options) {
```

But I get this ERROR in the console:

```
Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3LZdBl. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito).
```

Sorry, it is in Spanish. Any idea?

Comment: sorry, the error is

Comment: polling-xhr.js:267 GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3LscuG net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: You don’t have a CORS problem. Instead you have an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED problem. What happens if you try to open up http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3LZdBl (`http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3LZdBl`) directly in your browser?

Comment: The server you are trying to connect to should allow CORS. Try to look around for modules which allow you to do this. If you had used express for your node server you could use this module https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Yes, I tried wirh polling-xhr.js:267 GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3POYrr net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: But I can not connect. About the cors, I do not longer get that error.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the raspberry pi configuration.